# Search Results with category based URLs

Tags: categories, search, gwcode-categories

We have a site with 1 products channel and the URL's are constructed from the categories that the products fall into e.g.

`/template_group/category_parent/category_child/title`

This is all fine when generating links (via conditionals based on segments) within an exp:channel:entries tag however on the search results page I'm at a loss as to how to get the appropriate parent and child category entries into the URL to each result. 
Can anyone suggest an approach?!

Answer (score 0):

OK - I found a solution using the {categories} tags...

`<a href="/template_group{categories limit="1"}/{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}`">